# ajax getting only first value in foreach loop

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am working on rating and i want to get the rating for each id.but when i pass the value using ajax it only gets first value.I tried to get value using different methods.but everytime it pass first value.what can i do? i am stuck in that problem for a week.someone help me to fix this.

here is the code..

```js
$(function() {
  $('.rating').barrating({
    theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
    onSelect: function(value, text, event) {
      // Get element id by data-id attribute
      var el = this;
      var el_id = el.$elem.data('id');
      // rating was selected by a user
      if (typeof(event) !== 'undefined') {
        var split_id = el_id.split("_");
        var postid = split_id[1]; // postid
        var userid = "<?php echo $current_user_id; ?>";
        //problem in that line//  var order_id = $('.ordr_id').val();
        // AJAX Request
        $.ajax({
          url: 'rating_ajax.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            postid: postid,
            rating: value,
            userid: userid,
            order_id: order_id
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            // Update average
            var average = data['averageRating'];
            $('#avgrating_' + postid).text(average);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="post-action" style="text-align: right;margin: 15px 50px;">

  <?php 
      $userid = $current_user_id;

      $db->where("id", $orders['store_id']);
        
      $store_ratg = $db->getOne("store");
      $storid = $store_ratg['id'];

      $postid=$order_id;
                 

      $db->where("userid", $userid);
      $db->where("postid", $postid);
      $db->where("order_id", $storid);
      $fetchRating = $db->getOne('post_rating');
      $rating = $fetchRating['rating'];

      $query = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),1) as averageRating FROM 
      post_rating WHERE order_id=".$storid;
      $fetchAverage = $db->query($query);
      foreach ($fetchAverage as $fetch) {
      $averageRating = $fetch['averageRating'];

     if($averageRating <= 0){
        $averageRating = "No rating yet.";
    }
                               
                                  ?>

  <!-- Rating -->
  //problem in that line// <input class="ordr_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo 
               $storid; ?>">

  <select class='rating' id='rating_<?php echo $postid; ?>' data-id='rating_<?
                     php echo $postid; ?>'>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  <div style='clear: both;'></div>


  <!-- Set rating -->
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#rating_<?php echo $postid; ?>').barrating('set', <?php echo 
                                $rating; ?>);
    });
  </script>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: TL;DR: - do you have duplicate ID values in the HTML that are used in your Javascript?

Comment: Will the browser ignore the space within `data- id`?  I think that will cause a duplicate ID and an unclosed attribute

Comment: sir problem is not in that line it is working fine...problem in input value whose class is ordr_id which i have mention in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion: Add one more `data-attribute` over the select box for `order-id`

```
<select class='rating' id='rating_<?php echo $postid; ?>' data-orderid='<?php echo $storid; ?>'>
```

Now in jQuery change the code like this:

```
var order_id = el.$elem.data('orderid');
```

Note: Also as I checked your code and found that you haven't used the `data-id` attribute, so remove it.

Comment: You "fixed" their `data- id`

Comment: data-id is written fine in code..its typing mistake

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant thank you soo much sir...your suggestion worked